# How to get upper and lower confidence bound for "individual predicted values" when using lmer() in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models, confidence-interval

lets say I have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(142222)
num_lots <- 5

data <- data.frame(
  Category = rep(1:num_lots, each = 7),
  Time = c(0,3,6,9,12,18,24))

Time = c(0,3,6,9,12,18,24)
intercept <- t(matrix(rnorm(5, mean = 95, sd = 1), 5,7))
slope     <- t(matrix(rnorm(5, mean = -.1, sd = .1), 5,7))
noise     <- t(matrix(rnorm(35, mean = 0, sd = .1), 5,7))
parameter      <- intercept   + slope  * Time  + noise

Measurement <- matrix(parameter, 35,1)
dt <- cbind(data , Measurement)
```

The following code fits a fixed-effect and mixed-effect model to this data.
When using a fixed-effect model we can get the upper and lower %95 confidence bound on the individual predicted values by using `predict(model, interval = "confidence")` as shown in code bellow:

```
model <- lm(Measurement ~ Time, data = dt)
predict <- predict(model, interval = "confidence")

mix_model <- lmer(Measurement ~ Time + ( Time | Category), data = dt)
Predict_mix <- predict(mix_model , interval = "confidence")
conf_intervals <- confint(mix_model)
```

But when I do the same for my mixed_effect model to, as you can see, `predict(model, interval = "confidence")` provides doesn't give the confidence bounds. Is there a way to get the confidence bounds on the individual predicted values for the mixed-effect models?

Comment: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#lme4

Comment: Alternatively, you could bootstrap, see `help("bootMer")`.

Comment: FWIW `predict(..., se.fit=TRUE)` now works for the development version of `lme4` ...

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately there is an easy solution, there is a [Package](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/ciTools/html/add_ci.lmerMod.html) ,"ciTools", that calculates upper and lower confidence bounds for Linear Mixed Model Predictions.

```
mix_model <- lmer(Measurement ~ Time + ( Time | Category), data = dt)

dt <- add_ci(dt, mix_model , alpha = .05, yhatName = "pred", type = "boot")
print(dt )
```